# Advice on replacing Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0 for Microsoft .NET

Tags: wcf, web-services

Is there an easy way to replace code that uses Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0 for Microsoft .NET with someone less esoteric like WCF?

Answer (score 4):

WSE 3.0 is mostly about transport and message security, IIRC.  WCF is the latest approach from MS to these implementations, so you should consider WSE as deprecated.

Transitioning to WCF from WSE? Nothing easy. There are new constructs to understand how WCF channels work to provide the same functionality that WSE provided (and then some.)

And WCF is not less esoteric -- it's just differently esoteric. Both are quite complex with their implementations and configuration soup, but WCF has the blessing of continued support and development.

Comment: What really pisses me off is that all these standards were supposed to make things easier. WCF + WS-Security should just be an extra parameter or two on the call, but with 150,000 options available they couldn't build the client code that way.

Comment: Spot on. It's way over-complex, given what they're actually accomplishing. But hey, what should we expect from a working group of IBM, Microsoft and Verisign?  ;-)